# NDEFReader.write ignoring the abort signal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webnfc

I'm trying to create a simple web page that can read and write NFC tags. I also would like to have the functionality to cancel the write operation if need be. so I was following the examples [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NDEFReader/write). however, I ran into a problem where the abort signal is being ignored. this simple code can demonstrate the problem:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script>
        let data;
        let reset_controller = new AbortController();
        let ndef;


        try {
            ndef = new window.NDEFReader();

            ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", async () => {
                log_error('Cannot read data from the NFC tag.');
            });

            ndef.addEventListener("reading", async ({message, serialNumber}) => {
                data = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message.records[0].data.buffer);
                draw_info();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        function draw_info() {
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = `data is: ${data}`;
        }


        function reset() {
            console.log('Aborted!')
            reset_controller.abort();
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';
        }


        async function read_data() {
            data = await ndef.scan();
            draw_info();
        }

        async function write_data() {
            console.log('stating write')
            try {
                await ndef.write("some data", {
                    AbortSignal: reset_controller.signal
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="read_data()">Read</button>
<button onclick="write_data()">Write</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Rest</button>
<p id="data">data is: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

to repeat the problem:

1- click on the write button.

2- click on reset to cancel the write.

3. approach a tag.

the tag now contains the string 'some data' where it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found the problem.

when we pass the options object to the write function, the abort signal should be placed at 'signal' attribute not 'AbortSignal'

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. The key for the options dictionary should be `signal`, not `AbortSignal`. See code samples at https://web.dev/nfc/#abort-nfc-operations

```js
const abortController = new AbortController();
abortController.signal.onabort = event => {
  // All NFC operations have been aborted.
};

const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.scan({ signal: abortController.signal });

await ndef.write("Hello world", { signal: abortController.signal });

document.querySelector("#abortButton").onclick = event => {
  abortController.abort();
};
```